# Mostrar icono al lado del nombre si el usuario si es verificado

Tags: php, codeigniter

le pedi a un amigo un favor pero no pudo resolverlo y me dejo este codigo.
Lo que quiero lograr es que se muestre al lado del nombre del usuario (en su perfil) un icono check.
Osea, si en el indice "verified" = yes, mostrar ese icono. Sino, no

```
                                    <?php echo $this->crud_model->get_type_name_by_id('user',$user_id,'display_name');?>
                                       <?php 
                                           $verify = $this->db->where_in('verified'); 
                                       ?>
                                       <span <?php if($verify == 'yes')
                                            <?php if($verify == 'yes'){ 
                                                   <i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#ccc"></i>
                                                   } 
                                               ?>
                                       </span>
```

Alguien puede ayudarme? Gracias desde ya

Comment: ¿Por qué está dos veces la misma condición una seguida de otra?

Comment: ademas de la condición repetida tal vez el campo veriefied tiene cammel case, priueba con:

if(strtolower($verify) == 'yes'){ 
         <i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#ccc"></i>
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter maneja el paradigma MVC (Modelo, Vista, Controlador), por lo que el modelo debe de ser creado con el método que va a verificar al usuario.

```
public function verificado($id) { 
$this->db->select('verificado');
$this->db->where('verificado', 1); 
$this->db->limit(1);
$consult = $this->db->get('tu_tabla')->result_array();

return $consult;
}
```

Por lo tanto, tu controlador solo sería, incluir en tu construct el llamado a tu modelo.

```
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('tu_tabla');
}
```

Y tu controlador de esta manera:

```
public function tu_controlador() {
$tu_usuario = $usuario;
$usuario_verificado = $this->tu_tabla->verificado($tu_usuario);
$data = ['usuario_verificado' => $usuario_verificado];
$this->load->view('tu_vista');
}
```

Ahora en tu vista, podrás usar para validar:

```
<?php if($usuario_verificado) { ?>
<i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#ccc"></i>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Que es lo que va en $tu_usuario? Porque cada usuario tiene su propia id

Comment: Eso depende de como accedas a tus usuarios, cuando un usuario inicia sesión en el sistema, me imagino que almacenas un identificador para reconocerlo, eso es lo que iría ahí, aunque ese código no es para lo mencionado anteriormente.